# Cross-compiling on Windows in Eclipse for PPC 405 target

Tags: cross-compiling, powerpc

Does anybody out there know how to setup Eclipse with MinGW or Cygwin to build, develop and cross-compile code that is to be deployed on a machine with PPC 405 architecture ? Is it something as simple as setting the right flags for the compiler, or is there something more involved ? I'm developing on Windows for an embedded system running Linux on a PPC processor.  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this
http://kegel.com/crosstool/
it seems easy though it builds the toolchain
after building the toolchain for cygwin you may use it from eclipse

Comment: And for cross-compiling targeting ᴡindows® based powerpc *(ᴡindows® supported powerpc in the past)* ?